# Inconsistent Error When Building Connection String in pysftp

Tags: python, pyspark, pysftp

I'm trying to build a list of files in a particular directory on an SFTP server and capture some of the attributes of said files.  There's an issue that has been inconsistently popping up when connecting to the server, and I've been unable to find a solution.  I say the issue is inconsistent because I can run my Databricks notebook one minute and have it return this particular error but then run it a few minutes later and have it complete successfully with absolutely no changes made to the notebook at all.

```py
from base64 import decodebytes
import paramiko
import pysftp

keydata=b"""host key here"""
key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=decodebytes(keydata))

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys.add('123.456.7.890', 'ssh-rsa', key)

hostname = "123.456.7.890"
user = "username"
pw = "password"

with pysftp.Connection(host=hostname, username=user, password=pw, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    * actions once the connection has been established *
```

I get the below error message (when it does error out), and it flags the final line of code where I establish the SFTP connection as the culprit.  I am unable to reproduce this error on demand.  As I said, the code will sometimes run flawlessly and other times return the below error, even though I'm making no changes to the code between runs whatsoever.

```
Unknown exception: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string within a bytes or unicode object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-a488e5a9-de49-48a7-b684-893822004827/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2075, in run
    self.kex_engine.parse_next(ptype, m)
  File "/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-a488e5a9-de49-48a7-b684-893822004827/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/kex_curve25519.py", line 64, in parse_next
    return self._parse_kexecdh_reply(m)
  File "/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-a488e5a9-de49-48a7-b684-893822004827/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/kex_curve25519.py", line 128, in _parse_kexecdh_reply
    self.transport._verify_key(peer_host_key_bytes, sig)
  File "/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-a488e5a9-de49-48a7-b684-893822004827/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1886, in _verify_key
    if not key.verify_ssh_sig(self.H, Message(sig)):
  File "/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-a488e5a9-de49-48a7-b684-893822004827/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 134, in verify_ssh_sig
    msg.get_binary(), data, padding.PKCS1v15(), hashes.SHA1()
  File "/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-a488e5a9-de49-48a7-b684-893822004827/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py", line 474, in verify
    self._backend, data, algorithm
  File "/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-a488e5a9-de49-48a7-b684-893822004827/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.py", line 41, in _calculate_digest_and_algorithm
    hash_ctx.update(data)
  File "/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-a488e5a9-de49-48a7-b684-893822004827/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py", line 93, in update
    self._ctx.update(data)
  File "/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-a488e5a9-de49-48a7-b684-893822004827/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.py", line 50, in update
    data_ptr = self._backend._ffi.from_buffer(data)
TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string within a bytes or unicode object
```